# Debug OpenFX plugins in VEGAS Pro

Tags: visual-c++, sony, openfx

I'm creating an OpenFX plugin in C++, and using it on Vegas Pro 17 right now.

The plugin works until I try to call functions from a static library (i.e: zlib or any other libraries).
I attached the Visual Studio debugger to the Vegas Pro application and I can see my plugin gets unloaded, but it doesn't tell why.

I have tried using shared libraries instead, but I get the same problem.
Any ideas how can I debug this plugin?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s2w9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing dependency,

I found out where the VEGAS Pro logs are written using **Process Monitor** the log file I was looking for is **%LocalAppData%\VEGAS Pro\17.0\svfx_video_grovel_x64.log** the file showed an HRESULT code on my plugin, telling me there was a missing dependency.

Using **dumpbin.exe /DEPENDENTS** I could find which dependency was missing and I moved it to the VEGAS Pro directory.